# WD Unlocker doesn't appear

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a problem with the pop-up box wd unlocker. I had to remove my extern hard drive WD MY Book from the shell and connect it with cables adaptor to my laptop. But know my drive is recognize just as "USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge" - in properties appears to be the hard drive i want, but i can't unlock the hard because i do not have the pop-up box to unlock. Doesn't show either the virtual CD unlocker. So how can i unlock my hard drive?

Comment: A lot of WD external drives have some kind of odd 'fake' block size conversion in the hardware that reports to the OS. Once you remove it from the case it reports the correct size & nothing can read it unless you put it back in the case.

Comment: Why do you need WD Unlocker?

Comment: I need to unlock it because is password protected...and i had to remove it from the case because the electronic from the shell was damaged

Comment: Is this a drive with a triangular USB - SATA converter attached to PCB?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen yes, indeed.

Comment: Well, I think that's the issue then, encryption/decryption happens in this triangular PCB. Without it PC sees nothing but a binary blob.

Comment: - @JoepvanSteen  Ooo...i understand. If i will put another one, from a WD similar, a friend can give me one, this will be ok? Thank you for your time and answers @